# How to delete employees associated with department name using ASP.NET Core

Tags: html, asp.net-core

I have created employee and department model entities using one-to-many models' relationships and I want to delete the employee list created based on selecting the department name from the dropdown using the department id as a foreign key in ASP.NET Core.

Before fetching stored department names to dropdown even I can't create an employee list along with department name

Comment: ASP.NET Core is a **web stack** - deleting data typically is done on the **database level** - so we need to know what **database technology** you're using - not what web stack ....

Answer (score 0):

I am using SQLite database code first approach to delete employees based on the department name selected from the dropdown. I want to caret department name in the employee list before deleting the department for CRUD in asp.net core